# Why curvatures relieve stress?

Tags: forces, material-science, curvature, stress-strain, statics

Per example, we can stop a crack in a steel plate by drilling a hole at the end of it. Or we all know the famous example of popular science that airplane windows are round for the same  reasons.

Why curvatures relieve and corners concentrate stress?

Comment: Related (with nice pictures): [Why do airplanes have curved windows?](http://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/15779/why-do-airplanes-have-curved-windows)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each situation you might consider has its own specific reasons why curvature between surfaces reduces stress, but in general curvature helps distribute shear and bending stress across a larger area and in different directions rather than concentrating force in a more local area in a single direction as sharp, discontinuous joints do.

By distributing the force you reduce the chance that the ultimate shear or bending stress will be exceeded thus reducing the chance of failure.

Some materials are more sensitive to others to stress concentration by the way the molecules align and by the bonds that exist between them. Anisotropic materials are less sensitive to the direction in which stress is applied, while others can be highly sensitive.